# Modeling issues

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges

I'm trying to model some holes in a piece that must keep a smooth and round surface. At least also the edges of the holes must but be smooth. I tried different ways to do it but i'm to a deadlock.
[image]

I did the holes with the bool tool but now i don't know how to smooth them because of the geometry that after the booltool is dirty.
As you can see the shape is smooth but the holes are too sharp

[image]

This is the topology after the bool tool:

[image]
I tryied with the looptools but i find 2 more issues:
1) I can't decide where to cut holes, but i must loop a circle just where i have faces
[image]
2)when i extrude down the circle loops down, even if i bevel with many edges the shading is still wrong

[image][image]

Someone know how could i solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello :). Boolean operations usually require some manual retopology. Your topology isn't visible, please add an image of the mesh edit mode :).

Comment: You probably need to apply *smooth shading* to the boolean object.

Comment: @jachym-michal, that's one of the hardest things to do in 3d modeling..

Comment: Also check the LoopTool addon. I think that if you need to make some holes with a decent topology, it can really help you instead of using the boolean mod. Here some info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/mesh/looptools.html - here a youtube tutorial from Abbitt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2MjvKy1yCo

Comment: @stphnl329 Thanks i tryied  but just the inner faces shades smooth and the edges of the circle they remain sharp.

Comment: @JachymMichal i edited the mai question so you can see the topology.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use looptools and to fix your problems:

1. **decide where to cut**: you can edit the typology of the mesh to have faces and edges where you want (for example you can select an edge and move it with G + G to move along the actual shape or you can add more edge loop to create the geometry for your hole). To create a good topology: select faces, loopTool > Circle, inset a little bit (I), extrude to create the hole (E).
2. **strange shading**: you should use subdivision modifier to fix this (use 3 or 4).

p.s. you don't really need too many edges when you bevel:

[image]